In pytorch, how can I parallelize of a set of boolean functions that are executed (on a GPU) repeatedly?
I have a set of Boolean functions that are independent, and (hypothetically) can be executed in parallel. I want to call those same functions repeatedly. See the code below, in which the outputs of the functions ping-pong between the A and B memory locations. How can I force the "IN PARALLEL" lines to be run in parallel on an NVIDIA GPU with CUDA installed?
import torch

A = torch.tensor([True, False, True]).to('cuda')  # Initial values.
B = torch.tensor([False, True, True]).to('cuda')  # Values don't matter. Will write over them in the first iteration.

n_steps = 100

for step in range(n_steps):

    # Use values in A to compute new values in B.
    # How to run the three lines below IN PARALLEL?
    B[0] = torch.logical_and(torch.logical_or( A[0], A[1]), A[2])  # func1: Y0 = X0 | X1 & X2
    B[1] = torch.logical_or( torch.logical_or( A[0], A[1]), A[2])  # func2: Y1 = X0 | X1 | X2
    B[2] = torch.logical_and(torch.logical_and(A[0], A[1]), A[2])  # func3: Y2 = X0 & X1 & X2

    # Only after the above three lines above finish their computation (and B has new values), should the lines below be run.


    # Use values in B to compute new values in A.
    # Note that the functions below are identical to the ones above (which may allow for some additional acceleration?)
    # How to run the three lines below IN PARALLEL?
    A[0] = torch.logical_and(torch.logical_or( B[0], B[1]), B[2])  # func1: Y0 = X0 | X1 & X2
    A[1] = torch.logical_or( torch.logical_or( B[0], B[1]), B[2])  # func2: Y1 = X0 | X1 | X2
    A[2] = torch.logical_and(torch.logical_and(B[0], B[1]), B[2])  # func3: Y2 = X0 & X1 & X2

    # Only after the above three lines above finish their computation (and A has new values), should the next loop be run.


I assume that you have some additional data parallelism (more dimensions to the tensors) because 3 one does not use GPUs when the amount of parallelism is 3. The easiest would be to but the three independent operations on three independent CUDA streams such that they can run concurrently. As all three take the same input, it makes sense to fuse them into one kernel although one would still not give the three operations to different threads but do them "sequentially" in a single thread. There is pipelining on GPUs, so technically the three operations would be running in parallel.

Thanks, @paleonix. The code is just a short example. Real implementation would have thousands (maybe 10s of thousands) of Boolean functions to execute, and the individual functions would be more complex. More precisely, the A (and there also the B) array would be thousands of bools in length, and each function would operate on 3-10 of those bools.

The reason I would not start off putting the different functions to different threads is that doing so naively would result in warp divergence. GPUs at their core are built to do the same thing many times. So "thousands" of different boolean functions does not sound very suitable to GPU computing if there isn't a lot of times each single function is called (32 might be enough). The whole premise reminds me somewhat of this recent question.

@paleonix note the n_steps=100 loop in my example code. The functions are called 100 times in the example (or 200 times if you count both the computation of B and then the computation of A). I anticipate needing n_steps to be in the millions.

But those are sequential and wont help you with keeping the lanes of a warp busy.

Ok. They have to be sequential (the outer looping) and there is no way around that. However, regarding your statement... "thousands of different boolean functions does not sound very suitable to GPU," I should clarify that although there would be thousands of functions within the loop, they would not all be different. It might be closer to hundreds of unique functions, each of which could be run in parallel on dozens of different inputs.

@mattroos, are there any limits to the structure of your boolean functions?

That sounds better. Is it possible to have the data ordered by which operation is going to be applied to it?

@paleonix, I don't think so, unfortunately. One was to think of this is as a sparsely connected recurrent neural network in this the nodes are performing the Boolean functions and the edges are transmitting the 0s and 1s. The identity of each nodes functions might modeled as randomly drawn from a uniform distribution of functions.

@YakovDan, I'm not clear on what you're asking. Can you give an example of "limits to the structure?" I'm not certain, but most of the Boolean functions will take in 6 bits.

@mattroos I mean, is any form of a boolean function should be supported or perhaps you can write your functions as follows: (a & b) | (c & d) | (e & f) | ... etc
where a, b, c, d, e f ... can be any boolean variable (X0, X1...) with negations and repetitions.
IF you can write your boolean functions like that, then evaluating the functions boils down to a single matrix multiplication

@YakovDan, AFAIK any Boolean function or truth table can be converted to a sum-of-products form. I've thought about this and do indeed wonder if implementing the functions as matrix multiplications would result in faster execution.

@YakovDan, how would one go about converting a truth table (preferably) or a boolean expression to a matrix, for matrix-multiply implementation of the boolean function? I'm assuming the matrix/vector representations are as described in this post: https://ozaner.github.io/boolean-logic-with-matrices/

@mattroos
Indeed, any boolean function can be converted into a sum-of-products form (also called DNF). However, this conversion allows products over any finite amount of literals.
If you can limit yourself to products of two literals only, then (for example) (a & b) | (c &d) is just the dot product of (a,c) with (b, d) so it can be done by a single matrix multiplication.
If this is too restrictive, you can add intermediate literals, at the cost of more steps:
if you want (x1 & x2 & x3 & x4) | (x5 & x6 & x7 & x8) rename y1 = x1 & x2, y2 = x3 & x4, y3 = x5 & x6 etc...

@YakovDan, how would one represent the binary values? E.g., in your (a & b) | (c &d) example, if all bits are 1, then the dot product of (1, 1) and (1, 1) = 2 in the real number space, but obviously the answer we want is 1. What python/code would one use?

@mattroos when "anding" two binary values, ordinary multiplication works fine. When "oring", you just sum over all product terms. If one or more of the terms is 1, the sum will be greater than one. At those locations, just set it to 1. I.e. A[A >= 1] = 1.

I doubt that this is the best/fastest solution, but using torch.compile does provide acceleration. I haven't yet tested when scaling up to thousands of Boolean functions.
import torch
from time import time

A = torch.tensor([True, False, True]).to('cuda')  # Initial values.
B = torch.tensor([False, True, True]).to('cuda')  # Values don't matter. Will write over them in the first iteration

@torch.compile
def process(A, B, n_steps):
    for step in range(n_steps):

        # Use values in A to compute new values in B.
        # How to run the three lines below IN PARALLEL?
        B[0] = torch.logical_and(torch.logical_or( A[0], A[1]), A[2])  # func1: Y0 = X0 | X1 & X2
        B[1] = torch.logical_or( torch.logical_or( A[0], A[1]), A[2])  # func2: Y1 = X0 | X1 | X2
        B[2] = torch.logical_and(torch.logical_and(A[0], A[1]), A[2])  # func3: Y2 = X0 & X1 & X2
        # Only after the above three lines above finish their computation (and B has new values), should the lines below be run.

        # Use values in B to compute new values in A.
        # Note that the functions below are identical to the ones above (which may allow for some additional acceleration?)
        # How to run the three lines below IN PARALLEL?
        A[0] = torch.logical_and(torch.logical_or( B[0], B[1]), B[2])  # func1: Y0 = X0 | X1 & X2
        A[1] = torch.logical_or( torch.logical_or( B[0], B[1]), B[2])  # func2: Y1 = X0 | X1 | X2
        A[2] = torch.logical_and(torch.logical_and(B[0], B[1]), B[2])  # func3: Y2 = X0 & X1 & X2
        # Only after the above three lines above finish their computation (and A has new values), should the next loop be run.

    return A

# First run is slow due to compilation
t_start = time()
A = process(A, B, 100)
print(f'{time()-t_start} seconds')

# Runs are faster subsequently, and can be looped over to effectively increase n_steps
t_start = time()
A = process(A, B, 100)
print(f'{time()-t_start} seconds')

Output without @torch.compile decorator:
First run time: 0.12589144706726074 seconds
Second run time: 0.059000492095947266 seconds

Output with @torch.compile decorator:
First run time: 18.201257467269897 seconds
Second run time: 0.007639169692993164 seconds

